# How to do computed values in Coffeescript with MobX 4?

Tags: coffeescript, mobx

Using MobX 3 in Coffeescript, I could do this:

```
mobx  = require 'mobx'

state = mobx.observable
    items:['a','b']

compute = (key,fn)->
    obj = {}
    obj[key] = mobx.computed fn.bind state
    mobx.extendObservable state, obj

compute 'num', ->
    @items.length

mobx.autorun ->
    console.log "items = #{state.items}"

mobx.autorun ->
    console.log "num = #{state.num}"

state.items.push 'c'
```

...which works as expected,
but with MobX 4 that same codes gives the error:

> Error: [mobx] Passing a 'computed' as initial property value is no
>   longer supported by extendObservable. Use a getter or decorator
>   instead

All of the examples that I can find use Javascript with Classes and Decorators and Getters.

But Coffeescript does not really do "decorators" or "getters", and I would prefer not to use Classes ( I am old-school )

So...how can I create a computed "num" on my "state"?
Can my "compute()" function be altered to make it all work again?

Comment: can you link to one of these javascript examples?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured-out how to do it, and since there have been no answers....here it is:

```
compute = (key,fn)->
    Object.defineProperty observable_state, key,
        get: fn
        configurable: true
    obj = {}
    obj[key] = mobx.computed
    mobx.decorate observable_state,obj
```

First, you create a configurable "getter" (it must be configurable because MobX is going to re-configure it), then you call the "decorate" function ( instead of using ES6 decorators ).